# Submit a form in PHP containing replicated input fields

Tags: php, forms, post

I need to prepare a register log for different volley teams, where to check at each training presence/absence of the athletes.
My SQL has the following tables:
tab 1: athletes' name
tab 2: team names
tab 3: events (present / absent / late /etc.)
tab 4 (the register_log):  date, athlete name, team name, event

I have coded the PHP for the register ore or less as follows:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['squadra']) && $_GET['squadra'] =='I Divisione') 
{
        //gets the info of athlete name and team from tab 1 and 2
        $query = "SELECT s.id_squadra, a.id_atleta, a.nome_atleta,a.cognome_atleta,a.id_squadra FROM squadre s, atlete a WHERE s.nome_squadra = 'I Divisione' AND s.id_squadra =a.id_squadra"; 

        res = $mysqli->query($query);

               while ($row = $res->fetch_array (MYSQLI_ASSOC))
                    {
                        // get the data that I need for the label and hidden fields

                        $id_squadra = stripslashes($row['id_squadra']);
                        $id_atleta = stripslashes($row['id_atleta']);
                        $nome_atleta = stripslashes ($row['nome_atleta']);
                        $cognome_atleta = stripslashes($row['cognome_atleta']); ?>

                       <div>
                        <form id="registro" name = "registro" method= "post" action="esito_registro.php">
                            <!--label name for the register_log-->
                            </br><label for ="atleta"> <?php echo $nome_atleta . " " . $cognome_atleta ?> </label></br>
                            <input type="hidden" id="id_squadra" value="<?php $id_atleta?>">
                            <input type="hidden" id="id_atleta" value="<?php $id_squadra?>">
                            <?php

                                //gets the values from the table events (tab 3) as a series of checkboxes for each athlete

                                $query_presenze = "SELECT * FROM var_presenze";
                                $res_presenze = $mysqli->query($query_presenze);
                                while ($row_presenze = $res_presenze->fetch_array (MYSQLI_ASSOC))
                                {   
                                    $id_var_presenze = stripslashes($row_presenze['id_var_presenze']);
                                    $valore_pres = stripslashes($row_presenze['valore']);
                                    //stampa i checkbox con presenza/assenze
                                    ?> <label><input type ="checkbox" id="id_var_presenze" value ="<?php echo $id_var_presenze; ?>"/><?php echo $valore_pres; ?></label>

                                <?php 
                                }

            } ?>
                        </br>
                        <input name="aggiorna_registro" type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Aggiorna registro" />
                </form>
                </div>



<?php
//la parentesi sotto chiude il primisso if(isset)
}?>
```

However, having replicated the same type of field for each athlete (if I have 10 athletes in the team I will have 10 replicated checkboxes and hidden fields), the $_POST array brings only the last hiddden input and checkbox (i.e. those for the last athlete listed).

I can I get all of them?

Comment: add name for form elements name="somename[]" .

Comment: thanks, it seems a good solution